# Valores de Y proporcional

Tags: node.js, highcharts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá, como faço para deixar os valores de Y | proporcional sem alterar os valores para melhor visualização dos dados

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
        var socket = io();
        socket.emit('acc', 'operacoes');
        socket.on('operacoes', function(data) {
            var operacoes = data;
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'areaspline',
                    backgroundColor: 'none',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    spacingBottom: 0,
                    spacingTop: 0,
                    spacingLeft: 0,
                    spacingRight: 0,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
                            setInterval(function() {
                                socket.emit('acc', 'operacoes_ligacoes');
                            }, 1000);
                            var chart = this;
                            socket.on('qtd_ligacoes', function(data) {
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                                for (var i in data) {
                                    chart.series[i].addPoint([x, data[i]], true)
                                };
                                // Update x-axis range
                                //chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((new Date).getTime()-3600, (new Date).getTime());
                            });
                            setInterval(function() {
                                chart.xAxis[0].update({
                                    min: (new Date()).getTime() - 12000
                                });
                            }, 60000);
                        }
                    }
                },
                //categories: categorias,
                title: {
                    text: 'Entrada e saida de chamadas'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: false,
                    opposite: true,
                    minTickInterval: 1,
                    min: 0,
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>  ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2); + '<br/>'
                    }
                },
                credits: false,
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 9,
                    y: 10,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
                    labelFormatter: function() {
                        return '<div style="text-align: left; width:130px;float:left;">' + this.name + '</div> <div style="width:40px; float:left;text-align:right;">' + '</div>';
                    }
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    areaspline: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    series: {
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        background: 'none',
                        pointPadding: 0,
                        groupPadding: 0,
                    },
                },
                series: operacoes
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Seria bom você mostrar a lógica que está usando para gerar o gráfico, caso seja possível, para que possamos ajudá-lo melhor.

Comment: da uma olhada agora , não achei nenhuma configuração na api que me atenda

Comment: Qual é o aspeto de `var operacoes = data;`. Esse `data` é um objeto? talvez daria para converter os valores em percentagem?

Comment: ele traz em array as operacoes que estão na legenda ['GFK OI', 'BANCO BMG', 'MONTREAL', ...] os pontos no grafico eu atualizo no events: load{} do highcharts; se eu converter em porcentagem não daria na mesma? ja que os valores sao bem distantes